# jQuery dataTables fnFilter() - needs help some implementation

Tags: datatables, fnfilter

I have some issues with implementing `fnFilter()` in datatables structure.
This is my code for now..

```js
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
   oTable =  $('#table').dataTable({
      "autoWidth":true,
      "scrollY": "500px",
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      "paging": false,
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": "datatables-scripts/table_processing.php"           
   });   
});

function resetFilter() {
   var input = document.getElementById("search_string");
   var search= input.value 
   oTable.fnFilter(search, 1 );
}
```

Var search is some text that I get from input type text.

Comment: What happens? Any errors? How do you access the `sSearch` param in `table_processing.php`

Comment: There is no sSearch param in table_processing..

Comment: You need to get the `sSearch` parameter to use in your php code.  Use Firebug's Net panel to look at the XHR request for the datatable population.  you will see the `sSearch` parameter listed

Comment: but at the end I would like to do a negative search, for what I need fnfilter as I read...in this case I don't see the connection between sSearch and fnfilter..

Comment: I'm confused - are you trying to filter on the client side?

Comment: Yes...here is a link of what I am trying to do..

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3088/negative-filters-ie-how-do-you-search-for-cells-that-do-not-match-a-string

Comment: So you populate the datatable with ALL the data, then want to perform a client-side filter? I don't think that's possible using fnFilter() because you're using serverside data, so fnFilter() will try to filter the results of `table_processing.php`.

Comment: Yes I am populating the table with server-side data. Hmm I thought that this is possible..I mean, I can't find a good example for fnfilter when populating the table with server-side data...

Comment: The way to do it is as I mentioned in the 2nd comment.  [http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side)